# Microsoft Graph API - send email from multiple tenants

Tags: python, email, oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

We have many Linux servers that send out emails via command line to participants and members via M365 emails.  Currently, we use basic SMTP authentication for these.  We would like to start using modern authentication instead.  Some of the emails addresses are not controlled by us, and this way we wouldn't need the email password as part of our way of sending emails, just a token.

I've installed this library for Graph API with Python: https://github.com/O365/python-o365

and have two scripts:

authenticate.py

```
import re
import os
import json
import O365
from O365 import Account
from O365 import FileSystemTokenBackend

if not os.path.exists('auth'):
    print('auth directory does not exist.  Creating...')
    os.makedirs('auth')

c = json.loads(open('secret/secret.json').read())

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Authenticate email via M365 OAuth2.0 authentication.")

#required arguments
req = parser.add_argument_group('Required arguments')
req.add_argument('-e','--email', type=str, metavar='', required=True, help='Email address')

args = parser.parse_args()

credentials = (c['client_id'], c['client_secret'])

token_backend = FileSystemTokenBackend(token_path='auth', token_filename=args.email)

account = Account(credentials, token_backend=token_backend)

if account.authenticate(scopes=['https://graph.microsoft.com/.default']):
   print('Authenticated!')
```

emailer.py

```
import re
import os
import json
import O365
from O365 import Account
from O365 import FileSystemTokenBackend

c = json.loads(open('secret/secret.json').read())

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Send email via M365 OAuth2.0 authentication.")

#required arguments
req = parser.add_argument_group('Required arguments')
req.add_argument('-t','--to', nargs='+', type=str, required=True, help='To email address, space delimited')
req.add_argument('-u','--subject', type=str, required=True, help='Email subject')
req.add_argument('-o','--oauth', type=str, required=True, help='Email account for authentication')

#optional arguments
parser.add_argument('-m','--message', type=str, help='Email message')
parser.add_argument('-a','--attachment', nargs='+', type=str, help='Email attachment, space delimited')
parser.add_argument('-mf','--messageFile', type=str, help='Email message as HTML file')
parser.add_argument('-tm','--testMode', type=str, help='Run in test mode')
parser.add_argument('-cc','--cc', nargs='+', type=str, help='CC email address, space delimited')
parser.add_argument('-bcc','--bcc', nargs='+', type=str, help='BCC email address, space delimited')

args = parser.parse_args()

#checks local 'auth' directory for auth token with same name as sender
token_backend = FileSystemTokenBackend(token_path='auth', token_filename=args.oauth)

#check if both --message and --messageFiles are set, error out if so.
if args.message is not None and args.messageFile is not None:
    print("-mf/--messageFile and -m/--message can not both be set.  Exiting")
    exit()

if args.message is None and args.messageFile is None:
    print("Sending email with no body...")

#list auth tokens 
tokens = os.listdir('auth')

#check if email has auth token
if args.oauth not in tokens:
    print("Email address not authorized.  Use authorizeEmail.py to authorize a new email address.")
    exit()

credentials = (c['client_id'], c['client_secret'])

account = Account(credentials, token_backend=token_backend)

mailbox = account.mailbox()

m = account.new_message(resource=args.oauth)
m.subject = args.subject

if args.attachment is not None:
    for i in args.attachment:
        if os.path.isfile(i):
            m.attachments.add(i)
        else:
            print(i, "is not a valid file.  Skipping...")

if args.messageFile is not None:
    with open(args.messageFile) as f:
        m.body = f.read()
elif args.message is not None:
    m.body = args.message

for i in args.to:
    if re.fullmatch("([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)", i):
        m.to.add(i)
    else:
        print(i, "is not a valid email, skipping...")

if args.cc is not None:
    for i in args.cc:
        if re.fullmatch("([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)", i):
            m.cc.add(i)
        else:
            print(i, "is not a valid email, skipping...")

if args.bcc is not None:
    for i in args.bcc:
        if re.fullmatch("([a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9-]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9-.]+)", i):
            m.bcc.add(i)
        else:
            print(i, "is not a valid email, skipping...")

if args.testMode is None:
    if m.send():
        print("Email sent successfully")
else:
    print("Test mode invoked, email not sent.")
```

I have created an Azure app on Tenant A as multi-tenant and set the following permissions:

[image]

I can use authenticate.py with a non-admin account in Tenant A and authenticate and get my access token.  I can then use emailer.py to send an email as that non-admin user in Tenant A.  That all works as intended.  However, if I try to use authenticate.py with a non-admin user in Tenant B, I get a warning that it needs admin consent to function.  I then log in as my admin account on Tenant B, get the response URL and get my access token.

However, if I try to then use emailer.py with that access token and send emails as the non-admin account in Tenant B, I get this error (email in URL replaced):

```
Client Error: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/NONADMIN@TENANTB.COM/sendMail | Error Message: Access is denied. Check credentials and try again.
```

Is there a way to allow my app to send emails as users who are not part of my original Tenant A?  Also not opposed to using a CLI solution that already exists, but was not able to find much on my own.

Answer (score 1):

Currently you are authenticating as a user in a particular tenant. This is called a Delegated permission. Once you authenticate you have an access token for a specific user in that specific tenant and, as you are finding, it cant be used to send email in another tenant.

You will need to do one of two things:

1. Authenticate with each tenant using delegated permissions and send email using that token when you want to send email from that tenant.
2. You might want to consider authenticating using the OAuth Client Credential flow with Admin consent. It uses an app id and secret to authenticate with a Tenant without needing a user present each time you need a new access token (they expire). You will need a Tenant Admin to consent to your App Id once per tenant.  From then on you can get access tokens as often as you like for the Mail.Send permission scope and send email from each of those tenants.

Comment: & also set multi tenant property to 'true' in Azure AD when registering the app